Is this possible to implement custom LWC to replace field in dynamic form and intercept edit event to have the same look and feel?
Is this possible to implement custom LWC to replace field in dynamic form and intercept edit event to have the same look and feel?
Is there any edit event we could intercept?

We have also been searching for this. Our conclusion is that it is not possible at the moment. There is an idea (on the roadmap) for this: https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000PzbpNUAR/allow-a-custom-lwc-component-to-be-placed-inline-with-dynamic-forms-fields
There is also this: https://github.com/google/sf-evolve-forms/blob/main/evolve-forms/main/default/lwc/dynamicFormsElement/dynamicFormsElement.js
I did not have the time to investigate how this works… but the demo looks promising.

Welcome to Salesforce SE!  Whilst the github example may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.
